# How do I write this in pseudocode?

Tags: python, pseudocode, flowchart

I'm currently studying JavaScript in Computer Science and just need a little help on my pseudocode as I'm getting confused. The task is to create a phone troubleshooting system in python. I have finished my basic flow chart for Task 1 but I'm now struggling to write it in pseudocode due to the excessive amount of questions. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Flow Chart: [click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9kYvbwMV4pzczJoUUZLcW1mWmc/view?usp=sharing)

My started Pseudocode:

```
START
OUTPUT ‘screen question1 here’
INPUT ‘user answer’
IF answer1 = ‘yes’ THEN
    OUTPUT ‘screen question2 here’
    INPUT ‘user answer’
ELSE
    OUTPUT ‘battery question1 here’
    INPUT ‘user answer’
IF answer2 = ‘yes’ THEN
    OUTPUT ‘screen question3 here’
ELSE
```

Thanks.

Comment: You certainly could use a nested if structure like this. You might want to think about organizing data in a way that lets the computer do most of the work for you though.

Comment: I'm confused - you say you're learning JavaScript in the question, tag this with Python, and ask about pseudocode. How is this question related in any way to either JavaScript or Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
answeer=''
answer2=''
answer3=' '

print ('screen question1 here')
answer = input ('user answer')
if answer=='yes':
    print ('screen question2 here')
    answer2 = input('user answer') 
else:
    print ('battery question1 here')
    answer3 = input('user answer')

if answer2 == 'yes':
    print ('screen question3 here')
else:
    pass
```

This is just an idea, the rest it's up to you.

[See this code working here](https://repl.it/H9dj).